# How to avoid adding of inject method for each view?

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

Currently to get instance of for example Picasso in an activity, I need to add inject method to AppComponent. How to avoid adding of the inject method, because I have a lot of fragments and views where it should be injected:

AppComponent.class:

```
@ForApplication
@Singleton
@Component(
        modules = {AppModule.class,OkHttpClientModule.class,NetworkApiModule.class,NetworkAuthModule.class})
public interface AppComponent {
    void inject(Fragment1 obj);
    void inject(Fragment2 obj);
    void inject(Fragment3 obj);
    void inject(Fragment4 obj);    
    void inject(Fragment5 obj);    
    void inject(Fragment6 obj);
    ...
    }
```

Fragment1.class

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {
    @Inject Picasso mPicasso;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        MyApplication.getComponent(getContext()).inject(this);
    }
}
```

My classes :

AppModule.class:

```
@Module
public class AppModule {
    private MyApplication mApplication;

    public AppModule(@NonNull MyApplication mApplication) {
        this.mApplication = mApplication;
    }

    @Provides
    @NonNull
    @Singleton
    public Application provideApplication() {
        return mApplication;
    }


   @Provides
   @ForApplication
    Context provideContext(){
        return mApplication;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Picasso providesPicasso(@ForApplication Context context) {
        return new Picasso.Builder(context).build();
    }
}
```

ForApplication.class:

```
@Scope
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface ForApplication {
}
```

MyApplication.class

```
public class MyApplicationextends Application {
    static Context mContext;
    private AppComponent component;
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mContext = this;

        setupComponent();
    }

    private void setupComponent() {
        component = DaggerAppComponent.builder().appModule(new AppModule(this)).build();
        component.inject(this);
    }

    public AppComponent getComponent() {
        if (component==null)
            setupComponent();
        return component;
    }



public static AppComponent getComponent(Context context) {
        return ((MyApplication) context.getApplicationContext()).getComponent();
    }
```

**UPDATE**

I want also inject adapters for fragments, and if I'll add inject to BaseFragment then BaseFragment will have all adapters for all child fragments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it by adding [Delegate class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40097180/2425851) with [lombok library](https://projectlombok.org/download.html)

```
@Accessors(prefix = "m")
public class AdapterDelegate {
    @Getter @Inject Lazy<FlatAdapter> mFlatAdapterLazy;
    public AdapterDelegate(){
       MyApplication.getComponent(MyApplication.getContext()).inject(this);
    }

    public static AdapterDelegate get() {
        return new AdapterDelegate();
    }
}
```

And in an Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    FlatAdapter mFlatAdapter = AdapterDelegate.get().getFlatAdapterLazy().get();
```

Answer (score 2):

One solution would be to use inheritance for the injection.

Just define a BaseFragment with a @Inject Picasso instance, create a injection method in your DaggerComponent for this BaseFragment and call it in the onCreate method of the BaseFragment. The more specific Fragments like Fragment1, 2.. can inherit from this BaseFragment and use the Picasso instance.

Comment: I want to inject adapters for fragments, and if I'll add inject to BaseFragment then  BaseFragment will have all adapters for all child fragments

Comment: Are these Adapters accessible at same component as your picasso provider ? How do these adapters differ from each other ?

Comment: I think @Jacob bring a good answer on the table, but if you have to inject other members then you have no choice to do this separately for all of them!

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
public final class MySimpleDelegate {

    @Inject
    protected Picasso picasso;

    @Inject
    protected Lazy<AdapterOne> lazyAdapterOne;

    @Inject
    protected Provider<AdapterTwo> providerAdapterTwo;

    public MySimpleDelegate(Context context) {
        MyApplication.getComponent(context).inject(this);
    }

    @NonNull
    public void getPicasso() {
        return picasso;
    }

    @NonNull
    AdapterOne getAdapterOne() {
        // the object is injected when the following method is called
        return lazyAdapterOne.get();
    }

    @NonNull
    AdapterTwo getAdapterTwo() {
        // a new instance is created every time this methos is called
        return providerAdapterTwo.get();
    }
}

public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

    private MySimpleDelegate delegate;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        delegate = new MySimpleDelegate(getContext());

        Picasso picasso = delegate.getPicasso();
        AdapterOne one = delegate.getAdapterOne();
        AdapterTwo two = delegate.getAdapterTwo();
    }
}
```

By the way, if the only problem is Picasso, it also provides a 'setSingletonInstance' method. See [this link](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/picasso-customizing-picasso-with-picasso-builder)

**EDIT**

I believe that you can reach what you want using dagger's Provider or Lazy factories. See the example above.

Comment: this solution breaks dagger flexibility. So if TS wanted to add another dependency to his fragment he would create another delegate or after all create inject method for that fragment.

Comment: I really don't understand your comment, what is 'dagger flexibility'? Dagger is a general injection library and it's not necessary to let it work inside fragment or activities (that's its flexibility). This solution is simply delegating the injection to another class, in order to avoid to add every single view/fragment/activity to the component (that is what the author asked for).

Comment: Assume, that target fragment has over 20 dependencies. So how could you resolve that with such approach? Would you provide over 20 delegates? Moreover, it isn't reasonably to use this if our fragment had only picasso dependency, because it won't be ready to growing/scaling.

Comment: Can you tell me exactly where I suggest to create a delegate for every dependency? Read the question again: "How to avoid adding of the inject method, because I have a lot of fragments and views where it should be injected". This is a possible solution.

Comment: So i haven't say that you did that. I've just mentioned about a flaw in this approach.

Comment: @MimmoGrottoli can you post code of Provider and Lazy, and then I'll set you bounty

Comment: @NickUnuchek it means that you should find it in dagger library

Answer (score 1):

The solution is you can do the inheritance ex: use extend Activity or Fragment and do injection in *onCreate()* in those class

Below is the example what i do:

Graph.java

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {
        AppModule.class,
})

public interface Graph {

    void inject(BaseActivity activity);
    void inject(BaseFragment fragment);
}
```

BaseActivity.java

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    protected List<Subscription> mSubscriptions;

    @Inject
    protected SharedDB dm;

    @Inject
    protected RestApi restApi;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getGraph().inject(this);
    }

    public Graph getGraph() {
        return MyApplication.graph(this);
    }

    //...
}
```

BaseFragment.java

```
public class BaseFragment extends Fragment {

    protected List<Subscription> mSubscriptions;
    protected Unbinder unbinder;

    @Inject
    protected SharedDB dm;

    @Inject
    protected RestApi restApi;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getGraph().inject(this);
    }

    public Graph getGraph() {
        return MyApplication.graph(getActivity());
    }

    //....
}
```

MyApplication.java

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    private Graph mGraph;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        setGraph(DaggerGraph.builder()
                .appModule(new AppModule(this))
                .build());
    }

    public Graph getGraph() {
        return mGraph;
    }

    public void setGraph(Graph graph) {
        mGraph = graph;
    }

    public static Graph graph(Context context) {
        DominoApp app = (DominoApp) context.getApplicationContext();
        return app.getGraph();
    }

    //....
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't avoid adding inject method for each target class flat way, but you can avoid calling that inject method in each class using reflection. With [this solution](https://gist.github.com/konmik/6ac725fa7134402539c4) you may call inject method only in parent class and then `ComponentReflectionInjector` would provide dependencies for each child classes in inheritance chain.

How it would look like:

```
Component {
    void inject(Child b);
}

//Activity, fragment - no matter
class Parent {
    ComponentReflectionInjector componentReflectionInjector;
    void onCreate() {
        componentReflectionInjector = new ComponentReflectionInjector(Component.class, /* component instance*/);
        componentReflectionInjector.inject(this);
    }
}

//your fragment with Picasso
class Child extends Parent {
    @Inject MyDependency dependency;
}
```

And then dependencies would been accessible in `onCreate` method of `Child` class.

That is very [disputable solution](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/3f0aso/dagger2_injection_through_a_base_class/) would it worth for convenience to loose some performance and would it worth some possible problems with `ProGuard` after obfuscation, and dagger2 have been designed to not use reflection at all in DI frameworks, but still.